# how to access and edit python library config file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to set my AWS id and secret in `boto.cfg` for the AWS python library `"boto"`. I've installed it on my mac with `pip install` and I don't see it in `/etc`

How do I locate and access it or do I have to create it? And if so how?

Comment: Perhaps this would help http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/BotoConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer does not create a config file for you.  You have to manually create one.  You can create a system-wide config file in /etc/boto.cfg or a personal config file in ~/.boto.  Or you can create one somewhere else and point the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable at it.